# Simulating trading on BitGet exchange with TradingView / Pinescript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have a strategy that I've written in PineScript and have been backtesting it on Tradingview.  However, I want to try to emulate the BitGet exchange as closely as possible, including leverage, entry size, exchange fees, margin call action, etc.  As best as I can tell, the exchange doesn't margin call until the margin reserve has been 100% reached, then it calls 100% of the position.  Here are some example settings I'd like to try to emulate:

50x leverage
$40 entry each time
Margin call as described above
Pyramiding of up to 1000 entries
Exchange fee of 0.048%

With that, it looks like:

```
pyramiding=1000, 
default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity,
default_qty_value=5000,
margin_long=1,
margin_short=1
```

in order to simulate 50x leverage, but then I wouldn't be entering with $40 entries.

I'm just not clear on how to enter with a partial amount but with a defined leverage.  It also appears that partial margin calls occur, and when I tweak `margin_long=1` and `margin_short=1`, I am able to partially simulate the 100% margin call that happens on BitGet, but I'm not at all clear what I'm doing with those.

Any clarity would be helpful.

Thanks!